# Possible to nest Android views?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, components, custom-controls

Even if it's possible, is it best practice?  Or should I always use ViewGroup (or one of its subclasses) as the base class for custom components that will contain other ui components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Possible to nest Android views?

Not really.

> Or should I always use ViewGroup (or one of its subclasses) as the base class for custom components that will contain other ui components?

By definition, a `ViewGroup` is the type of `View` you use to hold other `Views`.

In theory, you could completely rewrite `ViewGroup` yourself, if you really wanted.